# How do I limit 10 number per line in python

Tags: python

What's the error here?. I cant print the CozaLoza, CozaWoza and LozaWoza. And it only prints from 1-109. I also wants to print 11 output per lines. How can I do that?

```
for num in range (1, 22):
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        print("Coza" )
    elif (num % 5 == 0):
        print("Loza")
    elif (num % 7 == 0):
        print("Woza")
    elif (num % 3 and num % 5 == 0):
        print(" CozaLoza")
    elif (num % 3 and num % 7 == 0):
        print("CozaWoza")
    elif (num % 5 and num % 7 == 0):
        print("LozaWoza")
    else :
        print (num)
```

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by " limit 10 number per line in python ?"  Do yo u mean to say the final else line should not show a number if it greater than 10 ?

Comment: Does question mean that you want to add some separators per each 10 lines?

Comment: Your post is not very clear, so at the moment I am not able to help you. You should really try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better at writing good questions.

Comment: I might guess that you don't want to print via the last line in your code more than 10 times in a row, because they'll all be on the same line.  But you're guaranteed to print "Coza" every three iterations, and that will end the line. So you'll never call the last line more than twice in a row before you end the line with "Coza".

Comment: Hey guys I have an example up there

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code as following:

```py
num = int ( input ( "Enter a number: " ) )

if num < 1 or num > 110:
    print("From 1-110 number is allowed")
else :
    for n in range ( 1, num ) :
        name = str(n)
        if n % 3 == 0:
            name = "Coza"
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            name = "Loza" 
        elif n % 7 == 0:
            name = "Woza"

        print(name, end=" ")

        if (n + 1) % 10 == 0:
            print("") # print new line each 10 number prints
```

The answer for your question is the use of `if (n+1) % 10 == 0` and under.

It prints *newline* for each 10 numbers because of every mupltiple of 10 is True on `(n+1) % 10 == 0`.

BUT it has some wrongs on other lines.

NOT the `for num in range(1, num)`, it is `for n in range(1, num)`. the `num` is same with a name of variable in loops and **it is ambiguous**.

you could omit bracket `(` and `)` at if, elif statement in Python. `if (A)` equals `if A` in python :)

anyway, this is the output when input is 55:

```
Enter a number: 55
1 2 Coza 4 Loza Coza Woza 8 Coza 
Loza 11 Coza 13 Woza Coza 16 17 Coza 19 
Loza Coza 22 23 Coza Loza 26 Coza Woza 29 
Coza 31 32 Coza 34 Loza Coza 37 38 Coza 
Loza 41 Coza 43 44 Coza 46 47 Coza Woza 
Loza Coza 52 53 Coza
```

**EDITED:** (by updated question)

when `num` is `10`, the code can be reached to `elif num % 3 and num % 5 == 0`? I don't think so. because it was already `True` on `elif num % 5 == 0` above.

you need to fix your if conditions as like:

```py
if num % 3 == 0:
    ...
elif num % 5 == 0:
    if num % 3:
        # CozaLoza
    else:
        # Loza
```

Comment: num = int ( input ( "Enter a number: " ) )
if num < 1 or num > 110 :
    print ( "From 1-110 number is allowed" )
else :
    for num in range (1, num ) :
        if (num % 3 == 0) :
            print ( "Coza" )
        elif (num % 5 == 0) :
            print ( "Loza" )
        elif (num % 7 == 0) :
            print ( "Woza" )
        elif (num % 3 and 5 == 0):
            print( " CozaLoza")
        elif (num % 3 and 7 == 0):
            print(( "CozaWoza"))
        elif (num % 5 and 7 == 0):
            print( "LozaWoza")
        else :
            print ( num )

Comment: Here's my updated code. Where do i put the needed code in order to print it in 10 output per lines horizontally

Comment: Here's the updated code. What's the error here?. I cant print the CozaLoza, CozaWoza and LozaWoza. And it only prints from 1-109. I also wants to print 11 output per lines. How can I do that? 


for num in range (1, 22):
    if (num % 3 == 0):
        print("Coza" )
    elif (num % 5 == 0):
        print("Loza")
    elif (num % 7 == 0):
        print("Woza")
    elif (num % 3 and num % 5 == 0):
        print(" CozaLoza")
    elif (num % 3 and num % 7 == 0):
        print("CozaWoza")
    elif (num % 5 and num % 7 == 0):
        print("LozaWoza")
    else :
        print (num)

Comment: @Christiannnn when `num` is `10`, the code can be reached to `elif num % 3 and num % 5 == 0`? I don't think so. because it was already `True` on `elif num % 5 == 0` above. try to fix your if conditions.

Comment: I don't get it man. Do you have any socmed so we can talk clearly?